# How to sum each field of two columns into one column

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a table (table1) :

```
=====================================
|  column1         |  Column2       |
=====+========+===============+=====|
|   1              |     1          |
|----+--------+---------------+-----|
|   2              |     2          |
|----+--------+---------------+-----|
```

I need this output

```
====================
|       Sum        |
=====+========+=====
|        2         |
|----+--------+----|
|        4         | 
|----+--------+----|
```

I basically just need the sum of each field side by side combined into one new column.

Comment: As this seems to have been a temporary mind block, I'm closing it out as too localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT column1+column2 as `sum`
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't is as simple like this?

```
SELECT (Column1 + Column2) `SUM`
FROM   tableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1692d/1)